# java create date for dayOfWeek and time without a specific date, i.e. valid for any Monday

Tags: java, localdate

How can I create a generic date (i.e. not attached to any actual `yyMMdd` but similar to:

```
val START = LocalTime.of(startHour, startMinute)
val END = LocalTime.of(endHour, endMinute)
```

However, I additionally want to include the `dayOfWeek`.

My intention is to calculate the overlap of time intervals, i.e. for two given (start, end) timestamps I want to calculate overlap with a specified weekday and time (i.e. like opening hours).

## edit

I am not sure if a custom class is good enough.
My intention is if I have a list of events like:

```
id,start,end
1,2018-01-01 08:00, 2018-01-01 08:00 || opening hours 8-10, duration: 1
2,2018-01-01 10:00, 2018-01-01 12:00 || opening hours 8-10, duration: 0
3,2018-01-02 10:00, 2018-01-02 12:00 || opening hours 10-15, duration 2
```

to validate if time interval of `start-end` intersects with another time interval (i.e. opening hours), but this other time interval depends on the day of week.

After constructing the object (where I currently have my probably as I can't combine dayOfWeek and Time in a generic way)

I would use `isBefore/isAfter` a couple of times and then calculate the duration of overlap.

Comment: With a class that has 3 fields: `dayOfWeek`, `startTime`, and `endTime`.

Comment: Was nothing to down vote. Upvoted!

Comment: `id,start,end` doesn't tell which day of the week the event is related to. Where does that information come from?

Comment: @ernest_k `temporal if necessary, though ` this sounds interesting. Basically yes (see the edit) I want to compare overlap duration of business hours (which can be different per day).

Comment: Dear Down-Voter, please leave a criticism along with your vote. I see nothing wrong with this rather interesting Question.

Comment: @GeorgHeiler This Question is still vague. If you gave a more thorough definition of your business problem, you might get more helpful answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the [`DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) enum built into Java. It offers seven predefined objects, one for every day of the week, such as `DayOfWeek.MONDAY`.

I don’t follow exactly your business problem, but it sounds like you need to define your own class.

```
public class Shift {
    DayOfWeek dayOfWeek ;
    LocalTime startTime , stopTime ;
}
```

Add a method that translates that into real moments.

```
public ZonedDateTime startAtDate( LocalDate ld , ZoneId z ) {
    LocalDate LocalDate = ld.with( TemporalAdjustors.previousOrSame( this.dayOfWeek ) ) ;
    ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of( localDate , this.startTime , z ) ;
    return zdt ;
}
```

You’ll likely want to add the *ThreeTen-Extra* library to your project. It offers classes such as `Interval` and `LocalDateTime` that you might find useful. These classes offer a bunch of comparison methods such as *abuts*, *overlaps*, etc.

Looks like that library lacks a `LocalTimeRange`, so might want to roll your own. Perhaps even donate such a class to that project.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Comment: Great idea. However, I am not sure how to combine this enum with a time i.e. opening hours something like: `LocalDateTime.of(DayOfWeek.FRIDAY, 8,0)` will not compile

Comment: @GeorgHeiler You create a class `DayOfWeekTime` with 2 fields: `dayOfWeek` and `time`.

Comment: This looks really interesting. Basically https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34312128/find-out-if-a-series-of-dates-covering-an-interval @Basil has the state of interval overlap handling changed since your linked answer?

Comment: @GeorgHeiler Not sure what you are asking in relation to that linked Question.

Comment: Regarding ThreeTen-Extra and calculation of overlapping interval.

Comment: @GeorgHeiler I don’t know what issue you are referring to.

Answer (score 1):

One simple approach is to use an enum map for those "standard" intervals.

Assuming the method below to calculate the overlap:

```
static int calculateOverlap(LocalTime expectedStartTime, LocalTime expectedEndTime, 
        LocalTime actualStartTime, LocalTime actualEndTime) {
    //calculate overlap...
}
```

You can look up the value in this way (using `Pair` for simplicity, you can use a custom class with two `LocalTime` fields):

```
Map<DayOfWeek, Pair<LocalTime, LocalTime>> openingHours = 
          new EnumMap<>(DayOfWeek.class);

openingHours.put(DayOfWeek.MONDAY, 
          Pair.of(LocalTime.of(8, 0), LocalTime.of(16, 0)));
openingHours.put(DayOfWeek.TUESDAY, 
          Pair.of(LocalTime.of(9, 0), LocalTime.of(17, 0)));
//...entries for other weekdays
```

And then look it up using:

```
MyEvent mondayEvent = ...

Pair<LocalTime, LocalTime> mondayHours = officialHours.get(DayOfWeek.MONDAY);
int overlap = calculateOverlap(mondayHours.getLeft(), mondayHours.getRight(),
        mondayEvent.getStart(), mondayEvent.getEnd());
```

Answer (score 1):

My lib [Time4J](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4J) (v5.0) offers following out-of-box-solution for your whole business problem:

```
DayPartitionRule rule =
    new DayPartitionBuilder()
        .addWeekdayRule(
            Weekday.MONDAY,
            ClockInterval.between(PlainTime.of(8, 0), PlainTime.of(10, 0)))
        .addWeekdayRule(
            Weekday.TUESDAY,
            ClockInterval.between(PlainTime.of(10, 0), PlainTime.of(15, 0)))
        .build();
Map<Integer, TimestampInterval> events = new HashMap<>();
events.put(
    1,
    TimestampInterval.between(
        PlainTimestamp.of(2018, 1, 1, 8, 0),
        PlainTimestamp.of(2018, 1, 1, 9, 0)));
events.put(
    2,
    TimestampInterval.between(
        PlainTimestamp.of(2018, 1, 1, 10, 0),
        PlainTimestamp.of(2018, 1, 1, 12, 0)));
events.put(
    3,
    TimestampInterval.between(
        PlainTimestamp.of(2018, 1, 2, 10, 0),
        PlainTimestamp.of(2018, 1, 2, 12, 0)));
events.forEach(
    (id, interval) -> System.out.println(
        "Event: " + id + " => "
            + Duration.formatter(ClockUnit.class, "#h:mm").format(
                interval
                    .streamPartitioned(rule)
                    .map(i -> i.getDuration(ClockUnit.HOURS, ClockUnit.MINUTES))
                    .collect(Duration.summingUp())
                    .with(Duration.STD_CLOCK_PERIOD)
            )));
```

Output:

> Event: 1 => 1:00
>
> Event: 2 => 0:00
>
> Event: 3 => 2:00

The algorithm uses the [range-package](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/range/package-summary.html) of Time4J and still works properly if you have more than one clock interval per day-of-week or if the input interval stretches over more than one day (which requires summing up durations).

By the way, I assume that your first interval line "2018-01-01 08:00, 2018-01-01 08:00" contains a typo so I have adjusted the end time to 9AM (resulting in the expected duration of one hour).